# Do I need to reinstall Windows 8 after installing an additional hard drive

Tags: windows, windows-8

Do I need to reinstall Windows 8 after installing an additional internal hard drive on my notebook?

Does the same answer apply to RAM as well?

Answer (score 3):

The following is usually true for *any* OS.

There are two specific scenarios where you may run into trouble here:

- Firstly, your new disk is somehow selected as the boot disk. Change this in BIOS and you should be good.
- The second is if you're running a 32-bit variant of Windows, and have upgraded from under 3.5 GB of RAM to over that, in which case you will need to do an upgrade to 64-bit. This would require need you to reinstall.

Practically, adding RAM is invisible, Windows will just pick up the added RAM, and go with it. Adding a HDD is almost as painless – install the drive, initialize and format it. As long as you didn't do anything to your boot drive, nothing will happen that will necessitate a reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of re-installation of OS, Windows 8 automatically detect your newly added hardware if in case your OS not detect the hardware the just go to control panel and  click on add hardware its scan newly added hardware and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you never need to reinstall your OS if you upgrade your hardware (HDD and RAM in this case) till you plan to trash your existing HD.

Answer (score -1):

no. you dont need to reinstall windows

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more as to why?